# In Ruby, if I declare a lambda function inside a loop, will it get cleaned up properly after each iteration?

Tags: ruby, loops, memory, lambda

I have something like this:

```
for i in 1..100000
    template = GetTemplate(i)

    set_setting_lam = lambda do |setting|
        (...) # Would prefer not to duplicate the code for the loops below
        template.setting = setting
    end

    for setting in settingArray
        set_setting_lam.call(setting)
    end

    for setting in settingList
        set_setting_lam.call(setting)
    end
end
```

Will this generate 100000 `set_setting_lam` objects, or will it clean up after each iteration?

Comment: Why would you need to create the lambda in the block? Why not create it outside the block? Lambdas and Procs to to create reusable code blocks for this purpose. You can pass as much information in as you need but create it once use it 100_000 times. Also you can avoid for loops which are generally considered code smell in ruby by using each. e.g. `(1..100_000).each{|n| puts n }` will output 1-100000.

Comment: The reason I want the lambda inside the block in this case is because template changes for every iteration. I could also pass `template` into the lambda function, but in the actual code I'm working on, multiple variables are set for each iteration of the block. I don't want to create a lambda that takes in 5+ parameters.

Comment: Why not? You could just pass a Hash argument that is built in the loop or better yet just combine the settingArray and settingList and iterate once without a lambda at all.

Comment: Stylistically, don't use `for` in Ruby code. Instead use `times` or `each` or `map` to iterate n times or over an array.

Comment: @engineersmnky I was more interested in the memory issue, but I agree with you.

Comment: The style isn't the best, but the question is more about the memory issue, so I'll like to focus on that. Having said that, I am keeping a mental note on all the styling improvements suggested (thank you for them =), but will not be responding to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda is an object just like any other object.

Of course, if you create an object in a loop that runs 100000 times, 100000 objects will be created. This is not specific to lambdas, it applies to *all* objects. And of course, once an object is no longer reachable, it becomes eligible for garbage collection. Again, this is not specific to lambdas, this applies to *all* objects.

The system decides when to run the garbage collector and how many and which objects to collect. If you don't run out of memory, the garbage collector may not run *at all*! Even if the garbage collector runs eventually, there is no way of telling *when* that will be. And even *when* it runs, there is no guarantee that it will collect *all* eligible objects and neither is there a way of telling *which* objects it will collect.

That's the *whole point* of automatic memory management: it's *automatic*!

Answer (score 4):

It will create objects, and they won't be cleaned up after each iteration based on this:

```
object_ids = []
1.upto(5) { |i| object_ids << lambda{ i }.object_id }
object_ids.each do |object_id|
  puts "#{ ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id) } - #{ ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id).call }"
end

#<Proc:0x007fae509c7380@test1.rb:2 (lambda)> - 1
#<Proc:0x007fae509c7330@test1.rb:2 (lambda)> - 2
#<Proc:0x007fae509c72e0@test1.rb:2 (lambda)> - 3
#<Proc:0x007fae509c7290@test1.rb:2 (lambda)> - 4
#<Proc:0x007fae509c7240@test1.rb:2 (lambda)> - 5
```

**UPD**

It will start garbage collection after some time, for 1000 objects 888 were still in memory after the cycle for me.

Comment: Not sure if that shows all objects are active / exist at once. According to http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-object_id: _The same number will be returned on all calls to id for a given object, and no two active objects will share an id._ Unique `object_id` values does not guarantee all those objects are active at once, does it (i.e. the converse is not guaranteed)?

Comment: @neverendingqs This is correct, and in my example you see that 5 objects were created and available after the loop, so they are in memory. You've asked "Will this generate 100000 set_setting_lam objects?", based on this example: yes, it will generate 100000 lambda objects and they are available, because I've sent `.call` to each lambda and all of them responded.

Comment: The garbage collector kicks in after a while - replace 5 with a larger number (1000 for me) and you'll see something like `_id2ref': 0x13a2c74 is recycled object (RangeError)`

Comment: @neverendingqs I see, it will clean up object after a while, for me, there were 888 objects still in memory after the cycle. So it will, but not after each iteration

Comment: This is really a garbage collection issue that has nothing to do with `proc`s. Each `lambda` created for one value of `template` is abandoned (can no longer be referenced) when the next one is created, and therefore will be hauled to the dump by the garbage collector, sooner or later. If the bin is getting too full between pickups, you can tune the collection schedule. In general, though, Ruby dosn't want us to have to worry about that. See, for example, [this](http://tmm1.net/ruby21-rgengc/).

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with @Rustam A. Gasanov's response, the answer is no: Ruby's garbage collector will start cleaning it up eventually, but not after each iteration.

Running:

```
object_ids = []
1.upto(1000) { |i| object_ids << lambda{ i }.object_id }
object_ids.each_with_index do |object_id, index|
  puts index
  puts "#{ ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id) } - #{ ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id).call }"
end
```

results in `_id2ref': 0x13a2c74 is recycled object (RangeError)` or something similar after a while (for me, it gave the error at index 160).